# How to render a container dynamically in react-redux?

Tags: react-redux

I am new to redux-react so excuse me if it is a stupid question.
I have a page which shows the list of some products in a table.
When I click on a product, I want to show details about that product in a panel overlaying the main page.

The problem is that the detail page has already a component and container class.
If I want to render the component I have to mix the main page and detail page containers together which I don't want. I want to keep each page component and container separate.

When I render container I get the error

> Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the context or props. Either wrap the root component in a , or explicitly pass "store" as a prop.

I don't know how to pass it and I googled about it I couldn't find a solution for my case. I don't want to initialize a new store.

Here is my click function to show the detail page.

```
onClick(){
    ReactDOM.render(
        <div>
            <div className="my-panel" id="my-panel" data-toggler=".is-active">
                <ProductDetailContainer />
                <button className="button" data-toggle="my-panel">Close</button>
           </div>
        </div>,
        wrapper
    );
}
```

here is my product detail container code:

```
export class ProductDetailContainer extends RootContainer {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        productDetail: {}
    };
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(someAction);
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    //some code here
}

handleRefresh() {
   //some code here
}

render() {
  return (
        <div className="row small-12 columns">
            <ProductDetailComponent                    
                data={this.state.productDetail}              
            />
        </div>
    );
}
}

ProductDetailContainer.propTypes = {
    productDetail: PropTypes.object
};


export function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        productDetail: state.productdetail
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ProductDetailContainer);
```

Comment: have you used `Provider` from react-redux?

Comment: please show us some code to inspect

Comment: @Utro if I add **Provider** I get the error I mentioned. **Invariant Violation**

Comment: @FaysalAhmed I updated the question with some codes.